# NameError: name 'train_files' is not defined ,NameError: name 'val_files' is not defined

Tags: python

I am getting error NameError: name 'train_files' is not defined ,NameError: name 'val_files' is not defined

```
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = len(train_files)//BATCH_SIZE
VAL_STEPS = len(val_files)//BATCH_SIZE

history = model.fit_generator(generator  = batch_generator(train_files, BATCH_SIZE),
                              epochs     = NUM_EPOCHS,
                              steps_per_epoch = STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                              class_weight = cl_weight, # Check if providing class weight is useful
                              validation_data = batch_generator(val_files, BATCH_SIZE), 
                              validation_steps = VAL_STEPS, 
                              callbacks = callbacks_list,
                             )
```

Comment: Simply what it means. Python doesn't know where your `train_files` comes from. Post the full code

Comment: and error as text

Comment: Here is the link of the full code is https://github.com/HareeshBahuleyan/music-genre-classification/blob/master/3.1_vgg_model_transfer_learning.ipynb